How to run pdb module commands in the code instead of in CLI?
I am working on a python debugger wherein I have a codespace (to enter code into) and some buttons (to control execution). I want to execute the entered code line-by-line on button click.
I found the pdb module which can help me add breakpoints and get values of variables in the code executed so far. However, this module can be operated only through CLI.
I want to run these commands (like continue, step-over) in the backend code triggered by some event (button-click here). How can I do this?
